# Relativsatz innerhalb eines Präpositionalobjektes

Tags: preposition, relative-clause, idiomaticity

Ich habe das folgende Präpositionalobjekt bei einem Artikel gefunden:

> über die damit verbundenen Erfolgschancen und Risiken nachdenken.

Ich weiß, dass solche Konstrunktionen nicht selten zu finden sind. Trotzdem stelle ich mir immer die Frage, warum man das in solchen Fällen nicht anders formuliert. Zum Beispiel, warum wendet man nicht einen Relativsatz innerhalb des Präpositionalobjektes an? In diesem Fall wäre das Präpositionalobjekt

> über die Erfolgschancen und Risiken, die damit verbunden sind,
>   nachdenken.

Ist das ein Thema vom Stil? Werden solche Konstruktionen (die Erste) nur in der Schrift benutzt? Benutzt man das auch im Alltagsgespräch? Ich frage, weil ich kein Muttersprachler bin.

Comment: Ja, es ist eine Frage des Stils. In den verschiedenen Stilebenen und -nischen der Sprache werden verschiedene Ausdrucksformen als angemessen oder unangemessen eingeschätzt. Beispielsatz 1 wäre typisch für eine hochformalisierte schriftliche Äußerung, Beispielsatz 2 eher für eine mündliche Äußerung. Am mündlichsten wäre wohl "Wir müssen mal über Chancen und Risiken nachdenken". "Die damit verbunden sind" fällt weg, weil es eigentlich redundant ist. Was für Chancen und Risiken denn sonst?

Comment: Sprache hat verschiedene Ausdrucksmöglichkeiten, und zwischen ihnen zu wählen erfordert immer eine Abwägung. Das Ziel "Kürze" spricht immer für die Partizipialkonstruktion. "Verständlichkeit" spricht für den Relativsatz oder gleich für zwei Hauptsätze + Anatapher. Der Wunsch, einen bestimmten Stil nachzuahmen, ist ein dritter Gesichtspunkt, und es gibt noch viele weitere. Deshalb kann es keine deterministische Antwort auf Fragen wie "Warum benutzt A die Konstruktion X?" geben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wie Christian schon richtig anmerkte, ist *die damit verbundenen* im Originalsatz ohnehin nur ein Füller. So sprechen höchstens Marketingprofis.

Ein einfacheres Beispiel:

> Lass uns über die heute gefundenen Fehler nachdenken.
>
> Lass uns über die Fehler nachdenken, die wir heute gefunden haben.

Hier würde ich auch im Mündlichen die erste Version bevorzugen. Einen Relativsatz würde ich nur benutzen, wenn der Wechsel des Subjekts wichtig ist, obwohl es da natürlich auch beide Varianten gibt:

> Lass uns über die heute vom Kunden gefundenen Fehler nachdenken.
>
> Lass uns über die Fehler nachdenken, die der Kunde heute gefunden hat.

Oder gleich

> Lass uns über die heutigen Fehler nachdenken.